# How to send mail using wordpress contact form 7 in localhost on ubuntu systems

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I searched on internet about how to send mail from localhost in wordpress on ubentu system. I tried to set up using sudo commands but not getting result again error comes

> > SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)SMTP connect() failed.

I tried with this [link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Comment: have you set your gmail credentials in main function?

Comment: yes i already did using sendgrid

Answer (score 1):

Just install mail SMTP plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/#installation and set your SMTP credentials.

After that mail will start going from your localhost.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have a SMTP server configured in your system or have your WP pointing towards a third party SMTP not sure if you have this already.

Comment: Have you checked if you have iptables blocking traffic to the server?